# Do I have a OpenLayers / jQuery conflict here?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, openlayers

Here is the coffee script code I have in my controller js.coffee file.  I am just trying to open a simple map centered on a specific location etc.  My map works and the `moveend_event` callback is triggered because if I uncomment the `alert("hello")` call it works fine.

```
$(document).ready ->

  map = undefined
  options =
    projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913')
    displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(-115.540123, 54.073189)
    controls: [new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(), new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(), new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher()]
    eventListeners:
      'moveend': moveend_event
  map = new OpenLayers.Map("map_element", options)
  osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM('OpenStreetMap Layer')
  map.addLayer osm
  map_center = new OpenLayers.LonLat(-115.540123, 54.073189).transform(new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"), map.getProjectionObject())
  map.setCenter(map_center, 11)

moveend_event = ->
  #alert "Hello!"
  #$(".map_location").innerHTML "Hello!"
```

I am close but can't I think I may have a Openlayers / jQuery conflict.  If I try setting my map_location div with `$(".map_location").innerHTML "Hello!"` the page creators and the error console shows:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating
>   '$(".map_location").innerHTML("Hello!")')

I have jquery loading before open layers if that helps.  I did some Googling and and it might be jQuery noConflict mode (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) but I am a javascript newbie and I don't know enough to recognize the issue here or how to fix it.  I am sure it's an easy fix but I currently do not have a clue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`innerHtml` is not a jQuery function, use `$('selector').html(new html here)`; instead.

`html` is jQuery counterpart of javascript's `innerHtml`

Comment: I am officially a dork - that fixed it.