# OpenLayers + Rails 3 + CoffeeScript = a.draw is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, openlayers

I don't understand why this won't work with Coffeescript. I tried to simplify this example: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/click-handler.html

In the view, I have a div with ID map and call initMap().

The error I got is:

```
 TypeError: a.draw is not a function
```

In the middle of openlayers lib

I got the following code in a .js.coffeescript file:

```
@MarkOnce = OpenLayers.Class OpenLayers.Control,
defaultHandlerOptions:
  'single': true
  'double': false
  'pixelTolerance': 0
  'stopSingle': false
  'stopDouble': false

initialize: ->
  this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend({}, this.defaultHandlerOptions)
  OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments)
  this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(this, {'click': this.mark},     this.handlerOptions)

mark: (evt) ->
  console.log 'mark'
  alert('pan')


 default_marker = (lonlat) ->
   size = new OpenLayers.Size(21,25)
   offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(-(size.w/2), -size.h)
   icon = new OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png',size,offset)
   marker = new OpenLayers.Marker(lonlat,icon)
return marker

  @initMap = (lon,lat,marker) ->
    @map = load_map(lon,lat)
    render_marker(@map,lon,lat) if marker
    set_projection(@map,lon,lat)
    set_callbacks(@map)

 load_map = (lon,lat) ->
   map = new OpenLayers.Map 'map'
   layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM()
   map.addLayer(layer)
   map

 set_projection = (map, lon, lat) ->
   projection = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
   point = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon,lat)
   console.log(point)
   center = point.transform(projection, map.getProjectionObject())
   map.setCenter(point, 5)

 render_marker = (map,lon,lat) ->
   layer_once = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("mark_once")
   map.addLayer(layer_once)

   lonlat = new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon,lat)
   layer_once.addMarker(@default_marker(lonlat))
   @numMarkers++

 set_callbacks = (map) ->
   click = new MarkOnce()
   map.addControl(click)
   click.activate()
```

EDIT: It seems that if you change the this.defaultHandlerOptions for {draw: -> alert 'pan'} it works. the question is now: What is happening in this scope? What is "this"?

EDIT2: One possible problem with this abordage is that whenever I zoom out or in in the map, the markers are placed in the center of the map. How to avoid this to happen?

EDIT3: If you get to this point, blow up whatever you are doing and go use leaflet .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with CoffeeScript creating a click-handler from OpenLayers.Control and OpenLayers.Handle.Click using OpenLayers.Class like you tried - but it seems thats not needed.

See [Do I have a OpenLayers / jQuery conflict here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312398/do-i-have-a-openlayers-jquery-conflict-here)
for how to establish an eventlistener in the options parameter of the map's constructor very easily. That worked fine for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, but It was a long time ago and I can't test if this solves the problem now. As stated, I ended up migrating to leaflet. But since you are reviving this, you should be right, so I'm setting your answer as accepted. And welcome to SO.